# Image Background - Button

Tags: html, css, button, background

How to insert background in button with width 100%?

```
   #test{
      position: relative;
      z-index:99; 
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    <button id="test"></button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gislef/mdngm86q/

Comment: Did you tried adding to your `#test` class property `background-size : contain;` ?

Comment: Thank you @Zeratops answer user Turnip is working

Comment: Do not forget to put Turnip answer as checked in order to classify this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `background-size`:

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%; /* or 100px or contain */
}
```

```html
<button id="test"></button>
```